# wicket ajax hide/unhide reusable panel withouth submiting form

Tags: ajax, wicket, panel, behavior

I prepared a reusable panel and add it to my page.
There are 2 dropdownchoice in my page's form.
im using the ajax example from https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/dropdownchoice-examples.html#DropDownChoiceExamples-Note
the two DDC works fine(change one's value then hide/unhide the other one.
but it doesnt work on my panel.
im using:

```
private final MyPanel panel1 = new MyPanel ("MyPanel"); 
panel1.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
```

... in DDC1 ajax behavior method:

```
onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) { ...
    DDC2.setVisible(true); 
    panel1.setVisible(true); 
}
```

I have to submit the form to hide/undide `panel1` .
How can I make it work the same way as `DDC2` without submitting the form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need :

```
panel1.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

The

```
panel1.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
```

that you have is actually not always needed for Ajax to work, but is needed for doing a refresh driven from the client side.  And it won't hurt anything to my knowledge ...

In the behavior you need to tell the target to refresh it:

```
onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) { ...
    DDC2.setVisible(true); 
    panel1.setVisible(true);
    target.addComponent(DDC2);
    target.addComponent(panel1); 
}
```

Comment: Right! I forgot to add target! thank you Don! Now I have 2 more questions. 1: after panel rendered, it automatically generates "Choose One" value for the second DDC, if I choose something then select "choose one" it will throw IBehaviorListener null pointer exception.  2. my panel also has multiple DDC and ajax behavior, how can I reset them when I change DDC value in my page? Thanks!

Comment: These sound like they might be worthy of new questions, with relevant code bits.  But the general advice is "use the models, luke".

Comment: Additional note on ```setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag```: you need it to render a container to the HTML markup even if ```isVisible()``` returns ```false```. Otherwise you will not be able to make it visible later using Ajax, as the client side cannot figure out where the resulting HTML snippet should be put into the DOM. So @Celia it is essential to use in your case.

Comment: I needed both, `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)` and  `setOutputMarkupId(true)` to be able to show and hide.